# Angular date-picker without day selection (only month and year)

Tags: angular, datepicker

I have a problem. I want to use a `date-picker` for an Angular form but I need to select only the **year** and the **month**, no need to select the day. What is the simple way to do that? Also I want to know how to take year and month separately to a `.ts` file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Angular Material DatePicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) with this workaround:

HTML:

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input #dpInput matInput [matDatepicker]="dp" placeholder="datepicker" [formControl]="date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #dp (monthSelected)="monthSelected($event, dp, dpInput)" startView="multi-year"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

ts:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-example.component.css'],
})
export class DatepickerFormatsExampleComponent {
  date = new FormControl(moment());

  monthSelected(event, dp, input) {
    dp.close();
    input.value = event.toISOString().split('-').join('/').substr(0, 7);
  }
}
```

The `monthSelected` function will get the datePicker and input references and will extract the selected data and set the value of input.

---

For the other part of your question, you can use `monthSelected` and `yearSelected` event, but they pass the entire date. What you can do is to extract these amount of the date object by the following:

```js
const array = event.toISOString().split('-');
const year = array[0];
const month = array[1];
```

Comment: **app.module.ts**

import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';

imports: [ 
    MatFormFieldModule,           
    MatDatepickerModule,        
    MatNativeDateModule,    
    MatInputModule
  ],